# removing certain <tr> from broken or Invalid HTML based on keyword

Tags: php, html

I am facing problem in removing certain `<tr>` from html retrieved from remote page, the main

problem is that html is invalid or broken my code works well on testing on valid well

formatted html but when it comes to the code of the remote page it doesn't work after some

experiments if found  that my be because the html code of the remote page is invalid

here is my code :

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://lsh.streamhunter.eu/static/section0.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
    @$doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query("//td[contains(., 'desktop')]"); // search td's that contain 'desktop'

    foreach($elements as $el){
        $parent = $el->parentNode;
        $parent->parentNode->removeChild($parent); // remove TR
        //$parent->removeChild($el); // remove TD
    }

    echo $doc->saveHTML(); // save new HTML
?>
```

it always give me 500 internal server error,
although when i test it on well formatted html it works well?

is there any thing i am missing in the code above ?
any suggestion to deal with this problem?

Comment: if you're getting an internal server error from a PHP page, you need to check the server logs to find out what the actual PHP error is. (or turn on error reporting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you're removing a TR, the next TD will be orphan, and you're probably getting that error because the `parentNode` property references a node that doesn't exist anymore.

Do this instead:

```
$toRemove = array();

// gather a list of TRs to remove
foreach($elements as $el)
  if(!in_array($el->parentNode, $toRemove, true))
    $toRemove[] = $el->parentNode;

// remove them
foreach($toRemove as $tr)
  $tr->parentNode->removeChild($tr);
```

Also, to suppress validation warnings add:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

before loading your HTML (and remove the `@` operator).

Comment: sir see this http://codepad.org/rrMdL4dh should the code now look like this? is yes i still doesn't work

Comment: yes this doesn't give internal server error but it removed all all <tr> not only the ones containing the word desktop I have no clue why?

Comment: how i remove the whole table table that contain that word i think if i removed the whole table things will be fine

Comment: The markup is invalid, that's probably why you're getting other TRs r emoved. [Here's another try](http://codepad.org/t4aqs2eK) without xpath

Comment: still removing all tr i think removing the whole table would be better and specific as the table contain only one tr

Comment: Well, then just query for `//table[contains(., 'desktop')]` and remove all elements directly

Comment: i dont know why it remove everything may be this is not the best way do this may we thing of jquery to hide the tr containing the word desktop

Comment: can we do it on the css as the tr i want to remove have the calss name `<tr class="sectiontableentry1">` but the problem that there is other tr with the same class name and i dont want to remove this. do u have any idea about this

Comment: i worked well when i changed it to remove the `tbody` thank you sir